# What time zones does DateTime accept?

Tags: perl, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I have tried to find out via the documentation but was not able to answer this question: What time_zone literals does `DateTime` in perl accept?

`CEST` is not valid. For `CET`, output is the current time but we currently have `CEST` timezone active.

What I am at: I would like to get the current time and find out what time it would be in `CET`.

If the server is running at `CEST` it should give as result the current time -1h. If the server is running at `CET`, it should give the current time.

My approach is:

```
$av_loc_TESTHOUR = DateTime->now(time_zone=>'CET')->strftime('%H');
```

which gives the current time of the server as result, but should give the current time -1h.

Comment: found a way on my own: perl -e 'use DateTime; my @av_tmp_DT=DateTime::TimeZone->all_names; print "@av_tmp_DT\n";'

Comment: I found a way to calculate the time in CET:
First I get the current hour on my mashine: $av_loc_TESTHOUR=DateTime->now(time_zone=>'CET')->strftime('%H');
Then I reduce the value by the offset if one: $av_loc_TESTHOUR-=DateTime->now(time_zone=>'CET')->is_dst();

Answer (score 2):

From the `DateTime` module's [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.26/lib/DateTime.pm):

> The time_zone parameter can be either a scalar or a `DateTime::TimeZone` object. A string will simply be passed to the `DateTime::TimeZone->new` method as its "name" parameter. This string may be an Olson DB time zone name ("America/Chicago"), an offset string ("+0630"), or the words "floating" or "local". See the `DateTime::TimeZone` documentation for more details.

The "for more details" documentation it refers to is [here](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-TimeZone-1.98/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm).

The "Olson" database it refers to is the standard IANA [TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), whose identifiers you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Identifiers like `"CET"` are only in the data for backwards compatibility purposes.  You should instead be using a fully qualified location-based time zone identifier, such as `"Europe/Paris"`.

Comment: yes, but "Europe/Berlin" does not help in this case. I need to calculate the time what hour it would be in CET regardless what we currently have on my mashine. BASH can do!
But I already posted the result I will use. Caused me some thinking around the corner but that is often the case in IT. At least it works.

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think you've thought this through carefully.  Please read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and the [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/634824) article.

Comment: I meanwhile have replace CET with "Europe/Berlin". Gives the same result but is saver as more compliant to "as designed".
The environment this conversion from CEST to CET must be done is complex and I do not want to bother you with this. At least, the solution posted works for me. So for the moment I will stay with this. Date/Time constructs are extremly challenging. It took me weeks until I got a working solution in bash. But thanks for hints.

Comment: How can I check is `$string` is a valid timezone accepted by `DateTime` ?